# for loop understanding

Tags: java

I'm not sure about how does for loop works can anyone explain it briefly to me?

For instance this code:

```
int count;

for(count=1;count <10; count = count+2)
System.out.print((3*count) + " " );
```

The answers are: `3 9 15 21 27`, but from where did the `9` come from?

Let's assume that the first count is executed so `1+2=3`, so `3*`1 = `3`.

Now aren't we suppose to take the `3` and sum it with the `2` and then multiply it by the 
`3`?

`5*3 = 15`, so where did the `9` come from?

Comment: In the first iteration `count` will be 1, and 3*1=3. in the second iteration `count` will be 3, and 3*3=9.

Comment: for each loop your variable count will have values 1 3 5 7 and 9. so the values

Comment: If you are just asking about loops, why tag it java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 parts of the for loop, separated by semicolons, give an initial assignment (which is executed just ones before going into the loop), a condition (which is checked for every iteration before going into the loop), and an update (which is executed after every iteration). Thus we have the following table

```
count  printed  condition
 1      3         1 < 10
 3      9         3 < 10
 5     15         5 < 10
 7     21         7 < 10
 9     27         9 < 10
11     --        11 < 10
```

which should make clear where the 9 comes from.

Answer (score 3):

The number that is printing out does not effect the variable `count`.

Since count starts at 1 and is increasing by 2 each time from the `count = count+2` it will be 1,3,5,7 .

This is then multiplied by 3 to give the output you are seeing.

```
1 * 3 = 3
3 * 3 = 9
5 * 3 = 15
```

To get the output you are expecting you want to change `count` inside the loop.

```
for(count=1;count <10; count = count+2)
count = count*3;
System.out.print((count) + " " );
```

This would output 15 as the second number then stop because it will be larger than the 10 to finish the forloop

Answer (score 3):

It comes from `3 * 3`.  `count` starts at `1` and is incremented to `3` via `count = count + 2` after the first loop.  The behavior you are describing should occur if you did this:

```
for (/*snip*/) {
    count = 3 * count;
}
```

That will output the 15 on the second iteration of the loop.

Comment: Good point on the assumption by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not assign `3*count` back to `count`, it simply prints the value.

When the loop is run, count takes the values {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}. On each iteration, the value of `3*count` is printed to stdout, *but `count` is not modified*.

---

Take this one step at a time:

1. `count` is initialized to 1.
2. `3*count + " "` is printed to stdout. (you get 3, and `count` *still has the value of 1*)
3. `count` is incremented by 2, setting `count` to 3.
4. `3*count + " "` is printed to stdout. (`count` now has a value of 3, so you get 9, again `count` is not modified)
5. `count` is incremented by 2, setting `count` to 5.
6. Output 15, `count` is still not modified.
7. `count` is again incremented by 2, setting `count` to 7.
8. Output 21.
9. Increment `count` to 9.
10. Output 27.
11. Increment `count` to 11.
12. The test `count < 10` fails so drop out of the loop.

---

Contrast this behavior with the following snippet, which may do what you expected:

```
int count;

for(count=1;count <10; count = count+2)
{
    count = 3*count;
    System.out.print((count) + " " );
}
```

But then this loop would also only execute for values of `count` in {1, 5} since 17 is greater than 10.

Comment: You probably don't want to times it by 3 again when you print it out...

Answer (score 1):

Print out count inside your loop and you'll see what's going on:

```
System.out.print("count: " + count + " (3*count): " + 3*count + "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

count starts at 1 and becomes the values {1,3,5,7,9}. Run this code and you'll be able to see for yourself what's happening:

```
for(count=1;count <10; count = count+2) {
    System.out.println("For count = " + count + ", Result: " + (3*count) + " " );
}
```

count does not increment for the first time until after the loop has completed it's first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
count
1     *3=
3     *3=
5     *3=
7     *3=
9     *3=
```